# Remover uma configuração de uma coluna mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma coluna mysql que possui uma `key` com valor `MUL`, como remover essa configuração pela linha de comando?

Minha tabela tem o seguinte esquema:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| imovel_id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| user_id         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| img_dest        | varchar(111) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| data_imob       | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| finalidade_imob | varchar(51)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| status_imob     | varchar(51)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| tipo_imob       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| uf_imob         | varchar(51)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| cidade_imob     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| bairro_imob     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| rua_imob        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| vaga_imob       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| dorms_imob      | char(2)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| tamanho_imob    | varchar(222) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| valor_imob      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
| titulo_imob     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| descricao_imob  | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| carac_imob      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta executar um alter table, e dropar o index da sua tabela:

`ALTER TABLE [nome_tabela] DROP INDEX [nome_index];`

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, eu sou novo no mysql, o que seria esse nome_index?

Comment: o nome do index que a coluna possui que seria a sua "key" que você especificou acima

Comment: Editei minha questão para você ter uma base de como é minha tabela eu gostaria de tirar a configuração da coluna `uf_imob`, eu não estou conseguindo.

Comment: execute um `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, e verifique o nome da Key referente ao valor, após isso execute o comando acima. qualquer coisa coloque na resposta o `CREATE TABLE` dela por favor:

Comment: o `MUL` só significa que é um index que não é unique, é multiplo. o nome dele você vai conseguir ver no CREATE TABLE ;)